# Missing file when installing pylinkgrammar

Tags: python, c, gcc

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylinkgrammar

I am encountering an error when attempting to install pylinkgrammar:

```
Running setup.py egg_info for package pylinkgrammar

Installing collected packages: pylinkgrammar
  Running setup.py install for pylinkgrammar
...
running build_ext

building 'pylinkgrammar/_clinkgrammar' extension

swigging pylinkgrammar/link_grammar.i to pylinkgrammar/link_grammar_wrap.c

swig -python -o pylinkgrammar/link_grammar_wrap.c pylinkgrammar/link_grammar.i

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pylinkgrammar/link_grammar_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pylinkgrammar/link_grammar_wrap.o

pylinkgrammar/link_grammar_wrap.c:2973:40: fatal error: link-grammar/link-includes.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install liblink-grammar4-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

Besides installing the liblink-grammar4 package also install liblink-grammar4-dev package which is available in synaptic.

I had been grappling with the same for over an hour and it worked for me

Comment: +1 Thanks that one worked for me...Not even mentioned here in youtube link about the dependency http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wk8zAr0R9zQ `liblink-grammar4-dev` is necessary

Answer (score 2):

You first need to install the liblink-grammar4 library:

If you're on ubuntu system, you can run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:python-pylinkgrammar/getsome
sudo apt-get install liblink-grammar4
```

If you're on a different flavor of linux, just make sure `liblink-grammar4` is installed.

Comment: right, because it's looking for a header file that exists in the debian package.  Install that using the commands in my answer, and then retry pip installing.

Comment: yeah did both sudo apt-add-repository ppa:python-pylinkgrammar/getsome
sudo apt-get install liblink-grammar4      still same error gcc

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

```
sudo apt-get install liblink-grammar4-dev cmake swig
sudo pip install pylinkgrammar
```