# installing pylinkgrammar on mac

Tags: python, cc

I am encountering an error when attempting to install [`pylinkgrammar`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylinkgrammar) on a Mac:

```
pylinkgrammar/link_grammar_wrap.c:2955:10: fatal error: 'link-grammar/link-includes.h' file     not found

#include <link-grammar/link-includes.h>


1 error generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

The same problem is described here: [Missing file when installing pylinkgrammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659118/missing-file-when-installing-pylinkgrammar)

But the solutions apply only for Ubuntu, since MacPorts does not have the packages `liblink-grammar4` and `liblink-grammar4-dev`.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that I have installed `link-grammar` using MacPorts. This error appears nonetheless.

Comment: It's in [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) though. `brew install link-grammar`.

Comment: I have installed link-grammar using macports, I suppose it is the same?

Comment: Can't say for sure, but the homebrew one worked just fine for me.

Comment: Thank you! using the homebrew installation solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the [MacPorts package](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/textproc/link-grammar/Portfile) doesn't include the development headers.

I was able to successfully build `pylinkgrammar` against the `link-grammar` package from [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh/) though:

- [Install `homebrew`](http://brew.sh/#install) if you haven't already
- `brew install link-grammar`

And then install `pylinkgrammar` as usual.

Comment: Hi, what ```link-grammar``` and ```pylinkgrammar``` versions are you using? I'm getting errors when I try a vanilla install

Comment: @AlexSpangher not sure what the version was I installed when I wrote this answer, but just tried with homebrew again, `link-grammar-5.3.15` and its Python bindings installed without a hitch.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, the brew install: ```brew install link-grammar``` works fine, and ```brew info link-grammar``` shows all the dependencies are successful, but when I try to ```pip install pylinkgrammar```, it's failing with a bunch of errors. Was the python binding you used ```pylinkgrammar```?

Comment: No worries ;-) No, I used (for testing, I'm not actually using LG currently) the Python bindings it comes with (`import linkgrammar`). Indeed, if I try `pip install pylinkgrammar` in a virtualenv, I also get a ton of compile time errors.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Seems like we're getting the same errors, then... unfortunate, as ```pylinkgrammar``` does seem to work in Ubuntu. Importing ```linkgrammar``` works for me, though. Thanks!

Comment: ```linkgrammar``` seems to be missing some functions that ```pylinkgrammar``` has, though, like ```dictionary_create```. Am I just missing something?

Comment: Not sure, it's been years since I used LG, sorry.

Comment: @AlexSpangher  The corresponding function in the current bindings for dictionary_create() is `Dictionary()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but pylinkgrammar was obsolete even then.
It works only with a very old release of Link-Grammar which is totally out of date.

The current Link-Grammar already includes the Python bindings (for both Python 2 & 3).
The fastest way to install it on Mac is still using Homebrew (as @LukasGraf mentioned in his answer).

([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49708694/6485214) includes info on how to use the Python bindings and how to interpret the sentence linkage output.)