# How to find invalid Link Grammar tokens?

Tags: python-3.x, validation, token, link-grammar

I'd like to use the [Link Grammar](https://github.com/opencog/link-grammar/tree/master/bindings/python3) Python3 bindings for a simple grammar checker. While the linkage API is relatively well-documented, there doesn't seem to be way to access all tokens that prevent linkages.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from linkgrammar import Sentence, ParseOptions, Dictionary, __version__
print('Link Grammar Version:', __version__)

for sentence in ['This is a valid sample sentence.', 'I Can Has Cheezburger?']:
    sent = Sentence(sentence, Dictionary(), ParseOptions())
    linkages = sent.parse()
    if len(linkages) > 0:
        print('Valid:', sentence)
    else:
        print('Invalid:', sentence)
```

(I used link-grammar-5.4.3 for my tests.)

When I analyzed the invalid sample sentence using the Link Parser command line tool, I got the following output:

```
linkparser> I Can Has Cheezburger?
No complete linkages found.
Found 1 linkage (1 had no P.P. violations) at null count 1
    Unique linkage, cost vector = (UNUSED=1 DIS= 0.10 LEN=7)

    +------------------Xp------------------+
    +------------->Wa--------------+       |
    |            +---G--+-----G----+       |
    |            |      |          |       |
LEFT-WALL [I] Can[!] Has[!] Cheezburger[!] ?
```

How do I get all potentially invalid tokens marked with [!] or [?] with Python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how it is done in `bindings/python-examples/sentence-check.py`.
It is better to look at the latest repo version [(the current one is here)](https://github.com/opencog/link-grammar/blob/6ad65148f9864f9fd5e0f4de2babd499386520a8/bindings/python-examples/sentence-check.py), as there was a bug in this demo program at 5.4.3.

Specifically, the following extracts the word list:

```
words = list(linkage.words())
```

Unlinked words are wrapped within `[]`. Words which have `[]` appended to them are guessed ones. For example, `[!]` means that the word has been classified by a regex (that appears in the file `4.0.regex`) and this classification has then been looked up in the dictionary. If you set the parse-option `display_morphology` to `True`, the classifying regex name appears after the `!`.

Here is the full legend of the word output format:

```
 [word]            Null-linked word
 word[!]           word classified by a regex
 word[!REGEX_NAME] word classified by REGEX_NAME (turn on by morphology=1)
 word[~]           word generated by a spell guess (unknown original word)
 word[&]           word run-on separated by a spell guess
 word[?]           word is unknown (looked up in the dict as UNKNOWN-WORD)
 word.POS          word found in the dictionary as word.POS
 word.#CORRECTION  word is probably a typo - got linked as CORRECTION

For dictionaries that support morphology (turn on by morphology=1):
 word=             A prefix morpheme
 =word             A suffix morpheme
 word.=            A stem
```

It may be useful to match the output words to the original sentence words, especially in case of spell corrections or when morphology is turned on. The said demo program `sentence-check.py` does that when you call it with `-p` - see the code under `if arg.position:`.

In the case of your demo sentence `I Can Has Cheezburger?`, only the word `I` has no linkage, and the other words have been classified as capitalized-words and got linked as proper nouns (the `G` link type).

You can find more information on the link types in [summarize-links](https://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/dict/summarize-links.html).